# What is "irmin-pack"?

Tags: kiln

In the last release of Kiln 0.8.0 is written:

> Updated tezos node dependencies to support the Carthage protocol and
>   the new, more compact storage backend (irmin-pack).

What is irmin? It is the repository?:

https://github.com/mirage/irmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> irmin-pack is an Irmin storage backend

https://tarides.com/blog/2020-09-01-introducing-irmin-pack